# CanActivate is not behaving as it should with Angular 7 with firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angular7

In my `Authservice`, I have:

```
  getAuthenticationState(): Observable<any> {
    return this.angularFireAuth.authState;
  }
```

And in my `Guard`:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        // In case of refresh
        return this.authService.getAuthenticationState()
        .pipe(map(user => !!user))
        .pipe(tap(loggedIn => {
            console.log(loggedIn);
            if (!loggedIn) {
                this.router.navigate(['/admin/login']);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }));
    }
```

My problem is that I have to click the login button **twice** (I'm sure it is implemented as it should), it seems that the Guard is not working as an Observable, the *loggedIn* value prints only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add take(1) to solve it and why you're using 2 pipes , change it to

```
 return this.authService.getAuthenticationState()
    .take(1)
    .pipe(
         map(user => !!user),
         tap(loggedIn => {
            console.log(loggedIn);
           if (!loggedIn) {
              this.router.navigate(['/admin/login']);
           } else {
              return true;
           }
         })
      );
```